# Navlinks not rendering nested routes in React Router v6.10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

As expected, when navigating to direct children such as `Develop`, the component rendered is `<Develop />`.

When navigating to sub-children such as `Web`, the route changes to */develop/web* as expected, however, the component that's rendered is of the parent `<Develop />`, instead of the expected component of `<Web />`.

I've tried structuring the BrowserRouter in various ways but it makes the most sense to me that `Web` should be a child of `Develop` with the route of */develop/web*. I've also tried using relative links with no success.

If I change the structure of BrowserRouter so that `Web` is a direct child (instead of a child of `Develop`), with a path of */develop/web*, the expected component of `<Web />` is rendered. Is there an alternative solution?

```
// index.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import Layout from './routes/Layout';
import ErrorPage from './routes/ErrorPage';
import Home from './routes/Home';
import Develop from './routes/Develop';
import Web from './routes/Web';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "develop",
        element: <Develop />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "web",
            element: <Web />,
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
// Layout.tsx
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <NavLink to={"/"}>
        Home
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to={"/develop"} end>
        Develop
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to={"/develop/web"} end>
        Web
      </NavLink>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `<Outlet />` to be used in parent route elements to render their child route elements.

[React Router Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet)